# Why when i nmap scan a machine i get the port 554 (RTSP) open?

Tags: nmap, ports, ctf

I train on vulnerable boxes and during my recon phase, I use nmap to collect info on open ports.

I use the command `nmap -sS [IP|URL]` and no matter the machine, I get the result that port 554 - RTSP open.

But my mate used the same command and didn't get the same report (his results seems more accurate). Whether it's a Tryhackme machine or a Root-me one, I still get the result that port 554 is open.

I can't understand the scan.
How can a basic training box have a RTSP port open?

[image]

[image]

Comment: As a side note, a CTF box has all kinds of ports open and lots of non-standard configurations. What *is* noteworthy is that that port is open for you and not others. That indicates the possibility of your environment affecting the scan.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the scan is picking up an open port on your router. Try using the `--reason` and `--traceroute` options to see what reason the port is showing open, and where in the route it's detecting it.

Try isolating the scan to a single port, comparing a know remote service port and the "phantom" one.

You can see a detailed explanation for this issue and troubleshooting method here https://hackerific.net/2016/03/20/false-positive-tcp-ports/